# How can i get mentioned user's username in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Read the title and will be glad if anyone can help me guys

For an example messages.mentions.first(). Like that, is there anything for mentioned user's username?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which efforts have you attempted? It does not look clear because it did not provide an example.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would be to use the `message.mentions.users.first()`, as this will actually give you the first user mentioned in a message. (message.mentions is not a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection)). If there are no users mentioned, the first will result in `undefined`, so you will probably want to check for that. Once you have a user, you will want to access the `username` property.

Example:

```js
// Assuming we just need a message event
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (user === undefined) {
    return; // Do not proceed, there is no user.
  }
  const name = user.username;
  // Do stuff with the username
})
```

Sources:
[message.mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)
[message.mentions.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users)

Answer (score 1):

`message.mentions.members.first().user.username;`

This would give you the username of the first mention.

You could also do `message.mentions.users.first().username;`